# How JMS work in Java?

Tags: java, jms

How does async JMS work? I've below sample code:

```
public class JmsAdapter implements MessageListener, ExceptionListener
{
private ConnectionFactory connFactory = null;
private Connection conn = null;
private Session session = null;

public void receiveMessages() 
{
    try
    {
        this.session = this.conn.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);

        this.conn.setExceptionListener(this);

        Destination destination = this.session.createQueue("SOME_QUEUE_NAME");

        this.consumer = this.session.createConsumer(destination);

        this.consumer.setMessageListener(this);

        this.conn.start();
    } 
    catch (JMSException e) 
    {
        //Handle JMS Exceptions Here
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) 
{
    try
    {
        //Do Message Processing Here

        //Message sucessfully processed...  Go ahead and commit the transaction.
        this.session.commit();
    }
    catch(SomeApplicationException e)
    {
        //Message processing failed.
        //Do whatever you need to do here for the exception.

        //NOTE: You may need to check the redelivery count of this message first
        //and just commit it after it fails a predefined number of times (Make sure you
        //store it somewhere if you don't want to lose it).  This way you're process isn't
        //handling the same failed message over and over again.
        this.session.rollback()
    }
}
```

}

But I'm new to Java & JMS. I'll probably consume messages in onMessage method. But I don't know how does it work exactly.

Do I need to add main method in JmsAdapter class? After adding main method, do I need to create a jar & then run the jar as "java -jar abc.jar"?

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: What I want to know is that if I add main method, should I simply call receiveMessages() in main? And then after running, will the listener keep on running? And if there are messages, will it retrieve automatically in onMessage method?

Also, if the listener is continuously listening, doesn't it take CPU??? In case of threads, when we create a thread & put it in sleep, the CPU utilization is zero, how doe it work in case of listener?

Note: I've only Tomcat server & I'll not be using any jms server. I'm not sure if listener needs any specific jms server such as JBoss? But in any case, please assume that I'll not be having anything except tomcat.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question has to do with JMS.  You seem to be asking "how to run a program in Java".

Comment: You do not create a main method, once deployed on a server, the onMessage() method handles any messages sent to the queue that your class is watching. onMessage() will contain the logic you want to execute when a message arrives to the queue.

Comment: What are you using for a JMS implementation?

Comment: @Logan, So, my JMSAdapter class will not have any main method, right? So, I should package this class in a jar & then deploy it by using "java -jar JMSAdapter &", right? How will compiler invoke receiveMessages() method?

Comment: @Dave, I've already Oracle Queue set up & we've some jobs which are doing creating messages in this queue. I just want to write a program which will continuously listen to the messages & process them as soon as they're available,

Comment: Ok I read your code again. I didn't look at receiveMessages. Yeah if you write your code this way you need a main method that creates a new instance of your class and then calls receiveMessages() to start it. So your main would have a JmsAdapter myAdapter = new JmsAdapter (); then myAdapter.reciveMessages(). What server are you using to run this?

Comment: I'm not real familiar with using just Tomcat. I recently did this same type of thing, but on a JBoss machine, which does have Tomcat embedded in it. I had a jar file with annotations that let JBoss know it was a MessageDrivenBean. Take a look at HornetQ from JBoss maybe, from what I can tell it's built more for this standalone type of setup. It also has a lot of sample code you can use to test it with.

Comment: Most JMS Examples I read were frustrating because they all created this connection first to send a message and then consume their own messages in that same class. That's fine for an example, but I don't think is practical or how they are actually used normally. I had 2 separate jar files one that sends JMS and one that would Receive JMS messages on the server.

Comment: @Logan, can you please tell me if I can use this JMSAdapter as a standalone program which I'll use to listen to message? Does listener classes like JMSAdapter in this case requires server like JBoss?? I was planning to use JMSAdapter as a standalone program & thinking that it'll run as its own without requiring any server. This JMSAdapter program is listening to oracle queue. Will that work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6518/discussion-between-logan-and-mike)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to learn to walk before you start trying to run.

- Read / do a tutorial on Java programming.  This should explain (among other things) how to compile and run a Java program from the command line.
- Read / do a tutorial on JMS.
- Read the Oracle material on how to create an executable JAR file.
- Figure out what it is you are trying to do ... and **design** your application.

---

Looking at what you've shown and told us:

- You *could* add a main method to that class, but to make an *executable* JAR file, you've got to create your JAR file with a manifest entry that specifies the name of the class with the main method.
- There's a lot more that you have to do before that code will work:

  - add code to (at least) log the exceptions that you are catching
  - add code to process the messages
  - add code to initialize the connection factory and connection objects
- And like I said above, you probably need some kind of design ... so that you don't end up with everything in a "kitchen sink" class.

---

> if I add main method, should I simply call receiveMessages() in main?

That is one approach.  But like I said, you really need to *design* your application.

> And then after running, will the listener keep on running?

It is not entirely clear.  It should keep running as long as the `main` thread is alive, but it is not immediately obvious what happens when your `main` method returns.  (It depends on whether the JMS threads are created as daemon threads, and that's not specified.)

> And if there are messages, will it retrieve automatically in onMessage method?

It would appear that each message is retrieved (read from the socket) *before* your `onMessage` method is called.

---

> Also, if the listener is continuously listening, doesn't it take CPU???

Not if it is implemented properly.

> In case of threads, when we create a thread & put it in sleep, the CPU utilization is zero, how doe it work in case of listener?

At a certain level, a listener thread will make a system call that *waits* for data to arrive on a network socket.  I don't know how it is exactly implemented, but this *could* be as simple as an `read()` call on the network socket's `InoutStream`.  No CPU is used by a thread while it waits in a blocking system call.

Comment: if I add main method, should I simply call receiveMessages() in main? And then after running, will the listener keep on running? And if there are messages, will it retrieve automatically in onMessage method?

Answer (score 0):

This link looks like a pretty good place with examples using Oracle AQ. There's an examples section that tells you how to setup the examples and run them. Hopefully this can help.

[Link to Oracle Advanced Queueing](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_advanced_queueing.html)